# How can we skip/bypass one flow in kaleo workflow in liferay?

Tags: workflow, liferay, liferay-6

Hi All,

I want to skip/bypass a flow in Liferay (V 6.0.5) kaleo workflow.

Example i have 3 flows:-
  1) programmer
  2) team lead
  3) Qa

Now, I want user to skip the flow in certain condition **(for e.g team lead)**.
So, can anybody can suggest how to achieve this task...?

Thanks

Comment: @Martin Gamulin, Can you suggest Laxman some suggestion....Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use condition in the workflow definition file.....

Comment: thanks for a quick response...
But i think it works in 6.1 and m using 6.0.5...
so, any other solution....